# How do I mimic POST method when scraping web page with Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

As a beginner to web scraping I'm following along this tutorial:
https://brennan.io/2016/03/02/logging-in-with-requests/

about how to scrape websites that requires login/session cookie. Above suggests that only hidden inputs are needed when POSTing to the login page.

So this is the code I ended up with:

```
import requests, lxml.html

URL = 'https://www.mypage.com/login'

#GET PAGE
s = requests.session()
login = s.get(URL)
login_html = lxml.html.fromstring(login.text)

#FIND FORMS
hidden_inputs = login_html.xpath(r'//form//input[@type="hidden"]')
form = {x.attrib["name"]: x.attrib["value"] for x in hidden_inputs}
form['username'] = 'myusername'
form['password'] = 'mypassword123'

#LOGIN
response = s.post('https://www.mypage.com/login', data=form)
```

However this is not working for the page I am trying to perform the actual login to. By looking into the inspector in Chrome I learned that the actual login (the initial POST method = JsonExecute) looked like this:

**General**

```
Request URL:https://www.mypage.com/services/PlainService.svc/JsonExecute
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:192.192.192.192:443
```

**Response Headers (22)**

**Request Headers (12)**

**Request Payload**

```
{method: "login", pageGuid:"ff0e9db6-c0bc-490d-9dd0-593c72689683",...}
   Data:{
      methodName:"Login"
      pageGuid:"ff0e9db6-c0bc-490d-9dd0-593c72689683"
      password:"mypassword123"
      username:"myusername"
   method:"Login"
   pageGuid:"ff0e9db6-c0bc-490d-9dd0-593c72689683"
```

What I noticed is that the Request URL is pointing toward something completely different than I was expecting and I realise that the tutorial won't help me here.

How do I mimic this POST method which I can perfectly follow from the inspector in Chrome?

Comment: Did you try `response = s.post('https://www.mypage.com/services/PlainService.svc/JsonExecute', data={"methodName":"Login",
      "pageGuid":"ff0e9db6-c0bc-490d-9dd0-593c72689683",
      "password":"mypassword123",
      "username":"myusername"})` ?

Comment: Yes, I receive [Response 400] and printing the respons in text: 
"The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.". Seems as if I am missing some parameter.